# rxTextToXdf to read commas as decimals

Tags: microsoft-r

I have a large text file that uses commas instead of periods to indicate decimals.

Is there a way to get the rxTexttoXdf function in the RevolScaleR package to view commas as periods?

I suspect I'm going to get so much flak for this post as it seems really simple

Edit:

I am currently using a workaround that involves importing the numeric columns as character type, followed by stripping the comma and replacing it with a period and then converting to numeric

```
library(dplyrXdf) 

imported_data %>% #dataset with character types 
mutate_if(is.character,
        funs(gsub(",",".",.))) %>% #replace commas for period
mutate_if(is.character, as.numeric) %>%  #convert character to numeric
persist(cleaned_file) # cleaned_file being a file path
```

It feels  like there are much cleaner ways of doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RxTextData` has a `decimalPoint` argument for just this purpose.

Assuming your text file is European csv (columns are `;` separated, `,` is the decimal point):

```
txt <- RxTextData("your/file.txt", decimalPoint=",", delimiter=";")
xdf <- rxDataStep(txt, "imported.xdf")

# do stuff with xdf
```

In general, it's a good idea to use data source objects to refer to files, rather than filenames. You can also use `rxDataStep` for just about everything.

Comment: Arg I cant believe that was so simple! Thank you very much - this is the second time you've answered one of my questions. Just a quick follow-up question - what's the difference between rxImport, rxDatastep, rxTextToXdf? It seems they all do roughly the same thing when importing text. (Btw dplyrXdf is awesome!!)

Comment: rxTextToXdf is a holdover from previous versions, when rxImport didn't exist. It's pretty much obsolete now. rxImport is almost obsolete; it has a few options that rxDataStep doesn't, and those options can also be specified in a data source object. rxDataStep should be your default in nearly all situations.